# Clarification on Lazy Loading -LINQ Query

Tags: entity-framework

Can you clarify this please?

```
public static void MyMethod()
        {
          var context= new MyModel.Entities();

          //myQuery will not have result yet
           var myQuery= from a in context.MyEntity where a.id==10 select a;

          // object is populated in myqueryResults.
           var MyqueryResults= myQuery.ToList();       
        }
```

My Understanding of Lazy Loading is, the properties will not populated until, you need, them.

**Question:**
There are no values coming back in myQuery, until we say `.ToList()`. So, Is this also a lazy loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not lazy-loading but lazy execution. Calling ToList twice will execute SQL two times. The result is not "cached" somewhere.

Actually, not ToList is the trigger but enumeration of the sequence. That's a difference.